# How should be open api v3.0.0 links implemented in the backend

Tags: api, backend, openapi

I am struggling to find an example code that has implemented and is using open api v3 links. How should the response look like coming from the backend, that has links described in open api, so that it would comply with the documentation?

Let's take an example from docs:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  version: 0.0.0
  title: Links example
paths:
  /users:
    post:
      summary: Creates a user and returns the user ID
      operationId: createUser
      requestBody:
        required: true
        description: A JSON object that contains the user name and age.
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/User'
      responses:
        '201':
          description: Created
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  id:
                    type: integer
                    format: int64
                    description: ID of the created user.
          # -----------------------------------------------------
          # Links
          # -----------------------------------------------------
          links:
            GetUserByUserId:   # <---- arbitrary name for the link
              operationId: getUser
              # or
              # operationRef: '#/paths/~1users~1{userId}/get'
              parameters:
                userId: '$response.body#/id'
              description: >
                The `id` value returned in the response can be used as
                the `userId` parameter in `GET /users/{userId}`.
          # -----------------------------------------------------
  /users/{userId}:
    get:
      summary: Gets a user by ID
      operationId: getUser
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: userId
          required: true
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int64
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A User object
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/User'
components:
  schemas:
    User:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          format: int64
          readOnly: true
        name:
          type: string
```

How response after `POST` should look like? Should it include nested object with direct links 
to that created user? Or should it only include id and client should figure out how to call that `GetUserByUserId` operation?

Basically, how should backend provide those links, described in openapi, so that client could use them? Is there any standard how to do it, or does it come down to personal preference?

Comment: I'm not aware of any tools that implement OAS3 links currently (May 2020). Based how this concept is defined, it's not supposed to be a backend thing, but rather a client-side traversal mechanism. That is, clients should analyse the OAS document to learn what they can do ( = which further operations they can call) using the values returned from some operation.

Comment: Also consider asking this question in the OpenAPI Specification repository: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues